# Can the cancel button on the shutdown pop up be disabled?

Tags: windows-7

As in the title, I would like it if the "waiting for programs to close" prompt did not have the ability to cancel a shutdown.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove the button - but you can keep Windows from prompting you if applications are still open when the [WaitToKillAppTimeOut](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978624.aspx) is reached.
Do this by opening regedit - go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Desktop/ and if not already present create a new entry called [AutoEndTasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978604.aspx) of Type REG_SZ with the value set to 1.